# Why can't Spyder select and read the selected file?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to practice data analysis and once I run the program, the console on Spyder gives me this error:

```
"File "C:\Users\RSTL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 624, in open raise IOError("%s not found." % path)

OSError: data_file.txt not found."
```

I have tried making sure my `anaconda`, `python`, and `python script` paths are added on the system. I chose both my user folder and desktop folder as the path for the program to use, making sure the file is saved to these folders respectively.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_file = np.loadtxt('data_file.txt', delimiter=',')

time = data_file[:,0]
```

It should open the file, read it, and label the first column as "Time".

Comment: Welcome teoe190. Did you try using the complete path to 'data_file.txt' on your call to _np.loadtxt_?

Comment: Have you gone to File explorer in Spyder and seeing what the wording directory is?

Comment: It seems the issue was that I did not have both the .py file and the .txt file saved to a viable folder, saving both files to my desktop and using it as my working directory solved the issue, thanks for the help